# at daemon creates empty tasks

Tags: scheduling, gnu, at

I have problem with `atd` daemon. If `at` is called by non-root, it creates task, but it is empty (content of `/var/spool/atd`). I do not remember what I have done before it broke that way. What else information should I provide and what what should I try to do?

Comment: atd is probably logging an error into your syslogs, look in /var/log/ for errors from atd.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. For atd it is not error, just empty script.

Comment: Hmmm, simple thing to check: `df`. Are you running out of disk space? Remember that the last few percent is reserved for root.

Comment: Great! I was really out of space.